# If $X$ is inductive, then, the set $U = \{ x \in X : x $ is transitive $ \}$ is inductive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set $T$ is transitive if $x \in T$ implies $x \subset T$.

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> If $X$ is inductive, then, the set $U = \{ x \in X : x $ is transitive $ \}$ is inductive. Hence, every $n \in N$ is transitive.

Proof: Let $\alpha \in U$. We have to show that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in U$. We know that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in X$, so it is left to show that it is transitive. So, let $\beta \in \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$. If $\beta \in \alpha$ then $\beta \subset \alpha$. If $\beta = \alpha$ then, obviously, $\beta \subset \alpha $. In either case we have $\beta \subset \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$ which implies $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$ is transitive.

What do you think. Is this proof ok?

Comment: What is your definition of inductive set?

Comment: I think inductive set is the set which contains $0=\{\}$ and for every $a$ in the set, its successor $a+1=a \cup \{ a \}$ is also in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in X$, then its successor, $S(x)$, is also in $X$ (because $X$ is inductive).

If $x$ is transitive, then $S(x)$ is also transitive (this is true for any transitive $x$, it's a good exercise to show).

If $x \in U$ (i.e. it's an element of $X$ *and* it's transitive), then so must $S(x)$ be.

Comment: I think this is exactly the exercise I was trying to do: "If $x$ is transitive, then $S(x)$ is also transitive". Hope my proof is ok. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Your proof looks good.